# How can I add an element to each Map in a List of Maps?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am storing each Firestore document's data into a list, but I also want to store the document ID with that data.

```
List<DocumentSnapshot> documentSnapshotsList =
                    querySnapshot.data.documents;

//Convert document snapshots list into a list of variations
List<Map> variationsData = documentSnapshotsList
                        .map((element) => element.data)
                        .toList();
```

But I don't know how to edit each element in a `List<Map>`. I do understand that the document ID is accessible via `DocumentSnapshot`.

Please feel free to share a better approach if you have one in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it using the below code:

```
List < DocumentSnapshot > documentSnapshotsList =
    querySnapshot.data.documents;

//Convert document snapshots list into a list of variations
List < Map > variationsData =
    documentSnapshotsList.map((element) {
        Map tempMap = element.data;
        tempMap['variationDocumentId'] = element.documentID;
        return tempMap;
    }).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty simple,

```
List<Map> variationsData = documentSnapshotsList
    .map((element) => {
        "id": element.id, 
        "key1": element.data["key1"], //customize your map accordingly
    }).toList();
```

Comment: Thanks, Raj, I knew I can do this, but this assumes that the keys are known for the coming document. I basically want to append the Document Id without knowing the contents of the document.

Comment: Do you want to add only the new elements or append existing too ??

Comment: I wanted to add an item to the existing data. I have found a solution and added it as an answer. I won't be able to mark it as the answer for 2 days due to the StackOverflow guidelines.